# How to Copy parent Directory Files in PHP

Tags: php, copy

Thanks in Advance. I am trying to Copy file in parent directory of script file.

Ex.
www.xyz.com/empty_page.php
www.xyz.com/empty_popup.php

Now my Script is Under admin forlder.
Ex.
www.xyz.com/admin/copy.php

in copy.php i put follow code but its not function

```
copy('../empty_page.php', '../new_page1.php');
copy('../empty_popup.php', '../new_popup1.php');
```

But its not working. if the copy.php is under www.xyz.com/ it will work with following code

Ex. www.xyz.com/copy.php (worked fine)

```
copy('empty_page.php', 'new_page1.php');
copy('empty_popup.php', 'new_popup1.php');
```

Please help me to solve this issue. Again Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You are trying to write a new file in the parent directory.  Make sure that the web server user has write permissions on the parent directory.

Comment: Thanks Michael... I am testing with localhost(Wamp Server) too... but not working :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about if you try something like this?

```
$path = dirname(__FILE__);
copy("$path/file1.php", "$path/file2.php");
```

Greatings.